# Significantly optimize byte operations in for loop (by avoiding a loop?)

Tags: java, android, performance, for-loop, bit-manipulation

I have to apply to each byte of my stream bit operations and arithmetical operations.

I identified the for loop in the code example as bottle neck of my output stream and like to optimize it. I'm just out of ideas ;)

```
    private static final long A = 0x1ABCDE361L;
    private static final long C = 0x87;
    private long x;

     //This method belongs to a class that extends java.io.FilteredOutputStream 
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            x = A * x + C & 0xffffffffffffL;
            buffer[offset + i] = 
                        (byte) (buffer[offset + i] ^ (x>>>16));
        }

        out.write(buffer, offset, length);
    }
```

The code is primarily used on Android devices.

## Update

I seek for at least 50% boost of the execution time. I learnt from my benchmarks with CRC32 that [CRC32#update(byte[] b, int off, int len)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html#update(byte[],%20int,%20int)) is ten times faster than [CRC32#update(byte b)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/CRC32.html#update(byte[])) on chunks greater than 30 bytes. (My chunks are > 4096 bytes) So, I guess I need some implementation that processes an array at once.

Comment: On Android you can use RenderScript to divide the operation on a bunch of GPU threads and make stuff much faster. Another way would be to make it multithreaded by hand, which would also give faster processing if the running device have multi-core processor. But I warn, that's quite some complex code, you might want to try to find some library to organize the syncing for you.

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @thepoosh It *could* be on CodeReview, but it's also a pretty valid Stack Overflow question. It's quite tightly scoped and asking a specific question.

Comment: @OneWorld Optimise what, specifically? Execution time, memory utilisation?

Comment: @Zak time and cpu usage. It decreases my uploading speed. It seems to execute inefficient. I feel I have to let the processor execute bigger chunks of data at once.

Comment: `x = A * x + C & 0xffffffffffffL;` You have a multiplication in the loop. I would take that out and do before the loop so you only have to do an addition in the loop. I would not trust the optimizer to do that for you.

Comment: @greenapps you can't take that out, because `x` changes with each iteration

Comment: Ha ha O yes.  I see now. Sorry  Sorry. Shame Shame.

Answer (score 1):

The follwing is a little bit faster on 32 bit cpus:

```
private static final long A = 0x1ABCDE361L;
private static final long C = 0x87;
private long x;

//This method belongs to a class that extends java.io.FilteredOutputStream
@Override
public void write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        x = A * x + C;
        buffer[offset + i] = (byte) (buffer[offset + i] ^ ((int)x>>>16));
    }

    out.write(buffer, offset, length);
}
```

Because of the right-shift of `x` by 16 bit and the casting to `byte` of the result of the xor-operation, effectively only the bits 16. to 23. are used of `x`, so it can be casted to 32 bits *before* the right-shift operation, making two operations faster on 32 bit cpus.